# Sum 2 counts from same table at end of row

Tags: mysql

I am using the query below to generate the table below that, what I would like is to get the total for each row at the end

```
SELECT
    FreeText,
    COUNT(case Status WHEN 'BOOKING' then 1 else null end) AS Bookings,
    COUNT(case Status WHEN 'QUOTE' then 1 else null end) AS Quotes
FROM
    orders
JOIN customers ON orders.CustomerNumber = customers.CustomerNumber
WHERE
    OrderDate <= CURDATE()
AND OrderDate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 31 DAY)
AND FreeText IN ('user1','user2','user3')
AND STATUS IN ('BOOKING', 'QUOTE')
GROUP BY
    FreeText
```

The above produces this table:

```
FreeText | Bookings | Quote
User1    | 23       |11
User2    | 11       |17
User3    | 8        |4
```

What I would like the query to produce:

```
FreeText | Bookings | Quote | Total
User1    | 23       |11     |34
User2    | 11       |17     |28
User3    | 8        |4      |12
```

Help much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `COUNT(*)` to the query.

```
SELECT
    FreeText,
    COUNT(case Status WHEN 'BOOKING' then 1 else null end) AS Bookings,
    COUNT(case Status WHEN 'QUOTE' then 1 else null end) AS Quotes,
    COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM
    orders
JOIN customers ON orders.CustomerNumber = customers.CustomerNumber
WHERE
    OrderDate <= CURDATE()
AND OrderDate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 31 DAY)
AND FreeText IN ('user1','user2','user3')
AND STATUS IN ('BOOKING', 'QUOTE')
GROUP BY
    FreeText
```

Comment: Is there a way that I can divide bookings and quotes for another coloumn?

Comment: You can put any conditions you want in a `CASE` statement to get more precise divisions. E.g. `CASE WHEN Status = 'Booking' AND Price < 100 THEN 1 END` (you don't need `ELSE NULL`, since that's the default).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    FreeText,
    COUNT(case Status WHEN 'BOOKING' then 1 else null end) AS Bookings,
    COUNT(case Status WHEN 'QUOTE' then 1 else null end) AS Quotes,COUNT(1) AS TOTAL
FROM
    orders
JOIN customers ON orders.CustomerNumber = customers.CustomerNumber
WHERE
    OrderDate <= CURDATE()
AND OrderDate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 31 DAY)
AND FreeText IN ('user1','user2','user3')
AND STATUS IN ('BOOKING', 'QUOTE')
GROUP BY
    FreeText
```

Try above query.

Comment: You should explain what you changed, not challenge readers to find the difference.

Comment: Both work but he got in before you, I upped your answer as it works

Comment: There's essentially no difference between `COUNT(1)` and `COUNT(*)`. Just different styles of coding.

Comment: What is the `@CNT` variable for? You're not using it anywhere. I guess you changed direction while you were editing.